# Cypress + Gapi.js auth testing

Tags: node.js, authentication, cypress, e2e-testing, google-api-js-client

I want to do full e2e with DB reset on each pre-commit on the local machine. So I trying to set up Cypress on the project with Gapi, which opens another browser window.

Is it even possible to take control of this process and get a valid g-token? Without the token, every API request will be failed.

Comment: Please add the code that you tried and also add errors if you got any.

Comment: @AlapanDas, I'm not even sure how to start with performing this. Which Cypress method could wait for google call in new window?

Comment: any luck? I ve started from intercepting the requests but I guess this will be too complicated this way

Comment: @kamiseq, https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/google-authentication this pretty much solves it. All you need is to have `refresh_token` in env file and keep it updated